# strtok() appends some character to my string

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm using strtok() to parse a string I get from fgets() that is separated by the ~ character

e.g. data_1~data_2

Here's a sample of my code:

```
fgets(buff, LINELEN, stdin);
pch = strtok(buff, " ~\n");
//do stuff
pch = strtok(NULL, " ~\n");
//do stuff
```

The first instance of strtok breaks it apart fine, I get data_1 as is, and strlen(data_1) provides the correct length of it. However, the second instance of strtok returns the string, with something appended to it.

With an input of `andrewjohn ~ jamessmith`, I printed out each character and the index, and I get this output:

```
a0
n1
d2
r3
e4
w5
j6
o7
h8
n9

j0
a1
m2
e3
s4
s5
m6
i7
t8
h9
10
```

What is that "11th" value corresponding to?

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buff[100];
    char * pch;
    fgets(buff, 100, stdin);
    pch = strtok(buff, " ~\n");
    printf("FIRST NAME\n");
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(pch); i++)
    {
        printf("%c %d %d\n", *(pch+i), *(pch+i), i);
    }
    printf("SECOND NAME\n");
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ~\n");
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(pch); i++)
    {
        printf("%c %d %d\n", *(pch+i), *(pch+i), i);
    }
}
```

I ran it by:

```
cat sample.in | ./myfile
```

Where sample.in had

```
andrewjohn ~ johnsmith
```

Output was:

`FIRST NAME
a 97 0
n 110 1
d 100 2
r 114 3
e 101 4
w 119 5
j 106 6
o 111 7
h 104 8
n 110 9
SECOND NAME
j 106 0
o 111 1
h 104 2
n 110 3
s 115 4
m 109 5
i 105 6
t 116 7
h 104 8
 13 9`

So the last character is ASCII value 13, which says it's a carriage return ('\r'). Why is this coming up?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Try printing the value of the character, not its looks: `printf("%d-%d\n", ch, index);`

Comment: I think 10 is printed because of line feed(Ascii value=10)  because of  `pch = strtok(NULL, " ~\n");` write like `pch = strtok(NULL, "~");` then i think it will be fine.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `strtok`? Specifically the part in bold: "The strtok function then searches from there for a character that is contained in the current delimiter string.  If no such character is found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to by s1.  **If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character, which terminates the current token.**" .... "Because strtok may modify the original string, that string should be duplicated if the string is to be re-used."

Comment: If I'm continuing to break down the string (and not re-using it later), wouldn't there be no point in duplicating it? By calling strtok on NULL, I should be able to continue breaking it down.

Comment: Let me guess, you edited the file on a Windows system (on which newlines are `"\r\n"`) and then run your program on a system or in an environment where newline is just plain newline.

Comment: What hex values does buff contain when you view it in your debugger?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - that was it exactly, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit, the input line ends in `\r\n`.  As a workaround you could just add `\r` to your list of tokens in strtok.

However, this should be investigated further.  `\r\n` is the line ending in a Windows file, but `stdin` is a text stream, so `\r\n` in a file would be converted to just `\n` in the `fgets` result.

Are you perhaps piping in a file that contains something weird like `\r\r\n` ? Try hex-dumping the file you're piping in to check this.

Another possible explanation might be that your Cygwin (or whatever) environment has somehow been configured not to translate line endings in a file piped in.

edit: Joachim's suggestion is much more likely - using a `\r\n` file on a non-Windows system. If this is the case , you can fix it by running `dos2unix` on the file.  But in accordance with the principle "accept everything, generate correctly" it would be useful for your program to handle this file.